# Shuffle an array multiple times without repeating values at any ID

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out a way to shuffle an array and get a completely unique result multiple times. I've been Googleing and searching this sight but yet to find the answer.

For example; let say I have an array $foo = [1, 2, 3, ... 99, 100] (array length will vary), I want to shuffle it multiple times (say, 5 times) where the value is not repeated at any ID.

As an example, imagine each line below represents a new shuffle and we're taking the value of $foo[0] (all IDs should follow the same logic).

This is good:

```
$foo[0] = 1
$foo[0]= 4
$foo[0]= 63
$foo[0]= 27
$foo[0]= 90
```

This is bad (Because 5 is repeated):

```
$foo[0]= 1
$foo[0]= 5
$foo[0]= 54
$foo[0]= 5
$foo[0]= 15
```

What method can I use to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this ? Or you want to repeat the process 5 times ?

```
<?php
// This is your array
 $array = array_fill(1, 10, true);
 echo print_r(array_rand($array, 5), true);
?>
```